# Mysql create database with new database location

Tags: mysql, sql, directory

Few months ago I have asked [a question regarding how to change database location at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092103/create-database-with-specific-data-file-location-in-mysql-for-one-database-at-run) - I didn't get any solution for this problem yet.

I am needing to create more than 32,000 databases in MySQL. The default data location of MySQL data folder, after creating 32,000 database on that location, I want to change the data directory to other location. I am planning to do this through Java code.

But before that can anyone tell me if this is possible?

I am really needing to implement this as an requirement. Please help me out with this.

I am sorry If I am unclear anywhere in this description, but let me know if you all need any more information.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you want to create 32,000 databases in the default MySQL DB directory, but then want to create all other databases in another directory? I don't think this is possible without recompiling MySQL.

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do ... but seriously, why would you want to do that?

Comment: Hi lan and Martin,

To your point lan, Yes I want to create 32000 databases in default mysql db directory or even more that 32000. and that too without recompling MySQL. As our servers cannot go down.
and yes Martin I am needing to do that. Is there any wayout pls help me.

Comment: You are trying to do stuff with a system that was not designed to do so, on a production system, and cannot even restart the service (which would result in ~10 seconds downtime)? I beg you to strongly reconsider your requirements.

Comment: If it's not a design problem of your implementation and only on partition type and/or OS
then change the partition type and/or OS.

Comment: I've acomplished something similar, check it out http://serverfault.com/questions/569182/mysql-hotcopy-and-symlinking

Answer (score 0):

That sounds difficult.  I don't understand why 32000 - is mysql refusing to create more databases than that?  What error do you get?  Seems arbitrary - maybe this is a config variable that can be changed?

A few possibilities.  You could run [more than one mysql server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/multiple-servers.html), each with a different data directory.  I don't think it would help, but you might look into the NDB storage engine, it can handle [tablespaces](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-tablespace.html) which just might let you store data in multiple locations.

Comment: Hi Keith,

Its not a mysql restriction but its a restriction of folder limit which is there on OS level. I cannot keep my those db's in NDB.

Comment: Are you using a FAT32 file system?  That's ancient technology.  Any modern file system can have way more items in a directory than that (NTFS for Windows, anything for Linux & Mac).

Comment: Then what OS & file system are you using?

Comment: Please also post the error mysql gives you when you do the create database that fails.

Comment: As I said earlier that mysql is not giving me an error for the problem of create more databases than 32000. But yes now mysql is giving me an error i.e. :- Can't create database (err:31).

Please help me.

Comment: OK, looks like you're running the ext3 filesystem.  I was unaware it had such a low directory limit.  You should use ext4 - check out http://serverfault.com/questions/74885/bypassing-the-32k-subdirectory-limit-dirnlink .  You could also use ReiserFS or XFS (check mysql docs to see if there are any issues with these).

Answer (score 0):

You can create several partitions and join them using LVM (this is in Linux) and mount the partition to the DATADIR path. Also you can use soft links the the databases moved to other folders/partitions.

Unfortunately MySQL supports only one DATADIR but it seemed to me that InnoDB tables can be places to separate path. Could you check this?