# Does mysql have any limitation on number of databases

Tags: mysql

I am creating mysql databases in mysql default data directory in "/Var/lib/mysql/data"
But it is not allowing me to create more than 31999 databases in it.

The similar sort of question I have asked before : 
[Mysql create database with new database location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607793/mysql-create-database-with-new-database-location)

Where I said that mysql can create more than 32000 databases but, when I tried this thing on production server. It is not happening.

Is there any possibility, where I can store databases on different locations.

any input will be an help.

thanks,

Manasi

Comment: For what do you need 32000 mysql databases? Smells like bad database structure.

Comment: 32,000 databases, on the same server instance?  I think I'm going to need popcorn...

Comment: If you have to ask, you're probably doing something wrong: http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/03/01/1775759.aspx

Comment: OP's profile says "I am MySQL DBA. New to MySQL". That alone deserves an up-vote; I'd up-vote twice if I could for sheer heroics of trying to create 32000 DBs on (presumably) the same server.

Comment: Hi All, Well it mgiht doesn't seem to be a good idea. but these databases will be very small in size and will be having 10 to 15 tables in it. But those needs to be created. Please advice.

Answer (score 7):

The MySQL manual states that there is no limit on the number of databases here: [maximum number of databases in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/database-count-limit.html)

However, since each databases requires the creation of one directory on the file system, and the file system may have a limit on the number of directories in one folder, there is an effective limit.

Check your file system documentation for the maximum number of directories it allows (NTFS ~ 4 billion, ext3 ~32000, ext4 ~unlimited, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

This might be a limitation of the file system your data directory resides on, because MySQL tries to create a directory for each database. If you cannot create more than a certain number of subdirectories inside a given parent, MySQL will fail on CREATE DATABASE.

**Edit:** As ysth says, multiple mysqld instances on different ports would pose a workaround. Most Linux distributions come with mysqld_multi prepackaged. This allows quite easily handling multiple database servers on one machine.

**Edit2:** According to Wikipedia (and my memory) "The max number of subdirectories in one directory is fixed to 32000" (see here: [Wikipedia ext3 entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3#Size_limits)), so as for that you are probably out of luck. Again, I think mysqld_multi is your best bet if you cannot get the number of databases down - or choose another filesystem that does not have this limitation (but might have others)

See the MySQL manual for more information on [mysqld_multi](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqld-multi.html)

Comment: If he is using ext3, then yes, he is limited to 32,000 directories (well, 31998 since you have to count `.` and `..`).

Comment: Thanks James, But is it possible to increase it and what will be the possible consequences of the same.

Thanks.

Comment: No, it's not possible except for using another filesystem which offers more subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any reason why you couldn't have multiple mysqld servers listening on different sockets/ports and using different data directories.  But rethinking whatever is causing you to want umpteen thousand databases would be better.

Answer (score 1):

maybe they are using multi-tenancy of type Database. This will create a new database for each tenant