# Load different database depend on user's log in?

Tags: php, mysql

I just wondering is it a good idea to loading different database based on user's log in detail. It's about assign a database to each individual user.

This is just a thought, i am developing an application (PHP) would like multiple users to use the app but without replicate the source code again and again, rather just load up different database.

The application is really a container of another application. So the user register under ***app-A***, and then have the permission to create, edit and update user in app-B.

I am talking about **app-A** in here.

My final question is:

Is it ok to do? What's the con and pro? Thanks for any suggestion or help.

Comment: sounds like a bad idea!

Comment: Why would you want to give each individual user their own database?

Comment: Don't you even think about it.

Comment: well they all say its bad, but i wrote a web app that does it (over 1k dbs, few thousand users), there are no absolutes. Not saying the OP should or shouldn't, way to little data to make that decision, but it is a valid option under specific circumstances.

Comment: @SheikhHeera I am just seeking suggestion, could you please identify the reason why?

Comment: @bluebill1049, just one question, how do you search a user record when you'll store them individually ? Please don't say that there are ways. Writing code doesn't make someone a programmer and every peace of code is not an application.

Comment: How many users are you talking about? You do realize you are limiting your app scalability and creating possibilities for future headaches...

Comment: @SheikhHeera hi sheikheera, i have update the post, i forgot to state its a app container really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to guess what you want to do without knowing your scenario, but in general multiple users can share a database. You just have to make sure you have some "user_id" field in your data rows in order to store information from different users.

Why do you think you need several databases?

One posible idea to recomend just one database: If you plan to have many users connecting and disconnecting, having different databases per user will be really slow, as database connections are slow to create. This is why "Connection pools" are created, and you would have a hard time to link a connection pool if you have a database per user.

If I understand well your updates, you are better off assigning roles to users and checking the permissions these users have in order to access data.

Comment: Because i am build an app as a container of another application, so depend on what user log in detail. single database won't work, or else i need to really replicate the source code and database to serve another user.

Comment: And what about creating subsets of tables for these individual users? You can have a table of users with a list of the tables you are using for their application. Then all users are in the same database. Your code will have to handle the creation/management of these tables, but you focus on this (that is somehow "interesting") and not in the initial user management (that is standard).

Comment: Thanks Moreno, The only concern the core database will gets huge in near future as the usage of the App-B increase. :)

Comment: I hope so, this would mean you have plenity of users ;-). Databases are nowadays able of handling a huge amount of data, so I would not worry about that. If you start worrying that you have so many users or the servers, hitting some database table limits or your server are getting too many requests (it should be not a problem at the very first stages of your project), then you can start planing your scalability strategy. (more in next comment)

Comment: For example, creating databases in different servers for users in different countries, or different proyects, or any  parameter that allows you to split the user base in several databases. This should mean just some modification in your code for load/balancing across several servers. In my opinion this is the way to go, I wish you good luck with your development!

Answer (score 1):

One Con I can directly think about is that you will need to make a DATABASE per USER.
If you have more than 32000 users, you may reach the maximum number of databases limit.

see: [Does mysql have any limitation on number of databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740391/does-mysql-have-any-limitation-on-number-of-databases)

Comment: not saying its a good idea, but that limit is trivial to get around

Comment: True..then again it's piling hacks on top of hacks. It all starts with one hack :)... and few years down the line they pile up sometimes.

Comment: that would be most of the code in the universe

Answer (score 1):

It is ok to do in a sense that it is technically possible, though highly inpractical. Having multiple databases greatly increases storage requirements, as SQL storage has a high redundancy, the switching of DBs can increase access time, and more then anything it will give you quite a headache to keep track of dozens of DBs. There are many ways of restricting user access to data in a DB, I'd suggest you use any one of them, you don't have to worry about too much data or high access times as SQL is generally ridiculously optimized, so unless you are developing a multi terabyte webportal for thousands of users you can shove everything in a single DB.