# Mysql server database limit

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to have 20,000 databases on a mysql server. They will not be accessed at the same time and there sizes should not be larger then 10mb. Lets just say that 5000 of them will be open at one time to various different sites. Could the server process that many queries with that many databases?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740391/does-mysql-have-any-limitation-on-number-of-databases
Please use search function!

Comment: That doesn't even answer my question, did you read it before?

Comment: This does answer your question, have your read the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/database-count-limit.html):

> MySQL has no limit on the number of databases. The underlying file system may have a limit on the number of tables. Individual storage engines may impose engine-specific constraints. InnoDB permits up to 4 billion tables.

However, there are other limitations, that may affect your setup:

1. Memory size, as MySQL will hold some information about each db in RAM
2. Disk space for transaction logs and cache
3. Number of simultaneous connections that can be handled by OS: each connections eats CPU, RAM, HDD.

Check out [E.7.6. Windows Platform Limitations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/limits-windows.html) - there is quite long list of things there.